# What string instrument is this?

Tags: instruments

I am "musically illiterate" and would like to know what instrument I hear in this video.

Comment: Sounds like a guitar to me.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because instrument identification is off-topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What Tim says in the comments, this is definitely an (acoustic) guitar, and a [classical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_guitar) one. The player is mostly picking single strings, but you hear a chord now and then.

As a comparison, [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MNWC4NMWfe8) is one of the first YouTube hits for "Spanish guitar". I hope you can hear it's the same instrument.